# REDIRECT BUTTON

Tags: html

How can I make a Button that has the function like the Facebook LIKE Page button? Is it Possible to change the word "Like" in the Facebook plug-in button ?[Like Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFxr8.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: @Arunava It's free for all to use: https://pastebin.com/Q3H7zcSn :)